# Request to rest api doesn't work by php curl but works by PhpStorm Rest Client

Tags: php, rest, curl

I'm trying to send request to rest api by curl but i have always 404 response. When i do the the same request by PhpStorm then my request works correctly. I set the same headers in rest client as in curl. What i do wrong? Below are my php code and screenshot of rest client configuration

```
    $postfields = array(
        'SUBSCRIPTION'                  => 'testlist',
        "HTTP_REDIRECT"                 => 'https://testsite.com',
        "HTTP_REDIRECT_ERROR"           => 'https://testsite.com/error',
        "email"                         => 'test+100@gmail.com',
        "Sprache"                       => 'DE'
    );


    $uri = $uri . '?=' . http_build_query($postfields); // value of uri is http://web.mailingsystem.com/subscription/servlet?=SUBSCRIPTION=testlist&HTTP_REDIRECT=https%3A%2F%2Ftestsite.com%2F&HTTP_REDIRECT_ERROR=https%3A%2F%2Ftestsite.com%2Ferror&email=test%2B100A%40gmail.com&Sprache=DE
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;from testshop;os:".PHP_OS.";)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

    $headers = [
        'Content-Length:'
    ];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);


    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    $error = curl_error($ch);
    $response = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

[image: rest client configuration]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first off, you send an incomplete "content-length" header. most likely, the target server treats this as "content-length: 0", but you should contact the developers of the api and tell them to fix it, so it returns a `400 Bad Request` response, not a `404 Not Found` response, then you should fix your code, so it has the correct content-length header. the best way to do that, is to not insert a  content-length header at all, which makes curl generate the correct one for you (when you have a request body)

second, your RestClient appears to be using `multipart/form-data`encoding, but your curl code doesn't have a request body at all, the data is in the GET url, fix that, so curl matches the RestClient thing, with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, like `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($postfields));` , and remove the data from the url. its probably because your url is malformed (contains the post data body), that you get the 404 error

Comment: thx for your help. I had to change both things according to your description and now it works correctly.